# What is going on with these 3 questions about WPF reorganising lists

Tags: discussion, duplicate-questions, low-quality-posts

A user seems to have created 3 very similar questions.
I am not certain they are identical.

- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25646652/change-order-of-items
- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25719508/resorting-of-existing-list-items-how
- [Logic Help for function Move up and Down in a listview](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25639753/logic-help-for-function-move-up-and-down-in-a-listview)

I'm not sure if they are duplicates, 
or if they represent continuing development of subsequent problems.

I think there are two problems -- one of how to move the items up and down, and one of how to renumber the items after they are moved.

I am honestly not sure which questions are asking about which problems. They are not fantastically written, though not truly terrible. My own ability to comprehend which is which may be lacking when I am flicking between the 3 of them.

I suspect they are duplicates and the user was re-asking the question because he didn't understand how the site works.

**Are they all valid? Should some or all of them be merged? Should some be closed and marked as duplicates?**

They almost definitely all need editing for clarity.

Comment: There is a lot of code posted, but that doesn't save them from being very poor questions.

Comment: OP also doesn't really seem to appreciate all the help offered. Poor questions and poor attitude if you ask me. Let's close what needs to be closed.

Comment: The frustration of everybody involved practically drips off those pages.  This needs to be done without all the theatrics and rudeness accusations, important to quickly close these questions to stop that from happening.  Pick anything.

Answer (score 4):

I think that "Change Order of Items" and "Resorting of Existing list items how?" are duplicates and now the latter has been marked as such. The other one doesn't appear to be a duplicate since as far as I can tell the one I answered does seem to hint towards some sort of data binding (which is what the answer of "Logic Help for function Move up and Down in a listview" recommends).

I think that two of these are genuine questions that the OP has come across whilst working on the *same* portion of his code. I don't see the problem with asking multiple questions that are closely related - provided it shows effort and are about separate issues.

The one question I did answer out of these I did try to address the OP's attitude, and modified the question to a point where it became clearer to what the OP was trying to achieve.

@Fry - If you do happen to read this, then please try to make sure you update your existing question with updated information rather than start a new question

Comment: Sometimes it can be much better to create new related question with new information. Particularly if you accidentally asked a slightly different but still valid question to what you had intended. Or if the extra information would change the answers, Eg if your decided to change from writing in C# to C++ that would *not* be a good time to update a question.
When it is worth asking a new questiom that is similar to a related one, then it can be good to link to the related question and say "From Here i learn that X, now with that solved I have issue Y"

Comment: @Oxinabox - If you have changed language, then you have created a separate but similar issue. The reason it becomes a separate issue is that you have changed what qualifies as a potential correct answer. If you have asked a slightly different question then you dont have a need to update the original (again its a new issue). But what you can do in these new questions is include a reference to the original question to show your previous research and attempts. If a question is a duplicate, it has to be attempting to resolve the same problem

Comment: Indeed, that is what I am saying. I agree.